# Passing the session source to a hidden field of an unbounce form

Tags: google-analytics, forms, url-parameters

It works fine if you go directly to to the form with a campaign link. But if you go to the website first and then click the button to get to the form - the source is gone from the url and so doesn't get added to the field.

I came up with a solution that rewrote the button link on dom load to append with a new parameter name whatever campaign parameters they arrive with. However - that will only work if they land on one page and go to the form. I could keep making the tag more complicated to cover more situations and that might be the right path.

But I would like to know if there is an easier solution at the source by adding a tag that only triggers when the form loads and pulls the referrer or utm_source and puts it into the hidden field.

Does this make sense what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need to track this yourself.  Google Analytics can attribute the conversions back to the source if you track the conversion as a goal in Google Anyltics.

Comment: Thank you, I do know that, and have that set up. Unfortunately the client would like the information autotagged in the salesforce data per profile/form fill.